# Recover my pendrive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I've got a problem with my pendrive.
I haven't used him for 2 months and now when I try to open it it says that it's unformatted.
Do you know any program (I prefer something free or opensource) which could retrieve these data?

The worse thing is that now I can't even format data.

Answer (score 4):

[Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) may be able to help

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). However, if you can't see the drive that suggests major file system corruption and it might take professional data recovery services to repair.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like **Pandora Recovery 2.1.1** - free file recovery software. This or any other similar program *may* work if the corruption isn't too bad. No guarantees.

I'm assuming that you're running Windows.

If this doesn't work you might have to accept that the pen drive is dead or will have to be reformatted to use again.

You can find Pandora here: http://download.cnet.com/Pandora-Recovery/3000-2094_4-10694796.html?tag=mncol

Please note that this is not a personal recommendation - I haven't used this program myself.